# Getting error in browser - Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope

Tags: javascript, reactjs, service-worker, msw

I am trying to use MSW for running my React app with mock data. Below is my *index.js*;

```js
import React from 'react';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
  const { worker } = require('./mocks/browser')
  worker.start().then(() => renderApp())
}
```

My service worker JS is located at *public/mockServiceWorker.js*

My *src/mocks/browser.js* is as below;

```js
import { setupWorker } from 'msw'
import { handlers } from './handlers'
// This configures a Service Worker with the given request handlers.
export const worker = setupWorker(...handlers)
```

Also my *src/mocks/index.js* is as below;

```
if (typeof window === "undefined") {
  const { server } = require("mocks/server");
  server.listen();
} else {
  const { worker } = require("mocks/browser");
  worker.start();
}
```

Now when running the app in browser, I see the following error;

> Failed to register a ServiceWorker for scope ('http://localhost:3000/') with script ('http://localhost:3000/mockServiceWorker.js'): The script has an unsupported MIME type ('text/html').

Also I am a bit confused as I am seeing an additional *serviceWorker.js* created under src (this seems to be generated via create-react-app) and as you can see above, this is also imported in *src/index.js* (again via create-react-app) , but the one I am looking to use is at *public/mockServiceWorker.js*

I am not sure if those are unrelated. I am trying to follow the example at https://github.com/ghoshnirmalya/introduction-to-msw

Also MSW official page for reference - https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using Create React App (CRA). The [MSW documentation](https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser#create-react-app-version-3) says that you should remove the line below from the `src/index.js` file:

```js
serviceWorker.unregister()
```

Did you do this?

The CRA template already comes with a service worker, this is why you have two files.

The CRA service worker is disabled by default (hence the `serviceWorker.unregister()` line). By removing the `unregister` line, you will be running the default service worker on production. Make sure that this is what you want.

Comment: Thanks...yes, that line is already uncommented (though I have the import still there ...import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';)...Also, I want the service worker from msw to be used for my app...Again, my intention is to run the app using mock data (which is what the msw library is included)

Comment: OK, have you tried replacing the CRA service worker script with your own? I know that CRA uses a lot of Webpack scripts to handle things, and it is very inflexible when it comes to service workers.

Comment: Another thing you could look into is building your app and checking the output folder to see if your script was bundled correctly. You may need to eject or use [React App Rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired).

Comment: Thanks...Not sure what is the difference between the service worker from CRA v/s the one suggested by MSW....as they say on this page (https://mswjs.io/docs/api/setup-worker/start) - Mock Service Worker distributes the Service Worker JavaScript module (mockServiceWorker.js) that is responsible for requests interception

Comment: I am slightly new to this service worker...so quite confused how to integrate within React app...I thought it should be straight-forward, but does not look like...

Comment: In terms of build output, I can see both the service workers js under the "build" directory

Comment: Well, in the past you could only use [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox) with CRA. But the MSW documentation says you can use it on CRA, so it should be possible.

Comment: If you get stuck for a long time, you could try to use Workbox to mirror the Mock Service worker: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-strategies#cache_only

Comment: Also, could you share the Service Worker script?

Comment: So the actual script can be found at https://github.com/mswjs/examples/blob/master/examples/rest-react/public/mockServiceWorker.js 

Also, could you please point out where MSW documentation says that we can use it on CRA..

Also, i am relatively new to this service workers...so not really sure how to use Workbox

Comment: Here, on this page: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser there is a mention to CRA. And also here: https://mswjs.io/docs/getting-started/integrate/browser#create-react-app-version-3. So I assume that it supports CRA.

Comment: As for Workbox, it can be confusing, but as far as I know, it is bundled inside the CRA app, so all you have to do is use it. You just have to enable the original service workers script from the template.

Comment: Actually seems like my public directory is not seen by the browser...coz whenever I try to do hit http://localhost:3000/<any_file_in_public_dir.js> , it redirects me to index.html

....So I assume we'll need to first identify why it is not able to access assets under public from the browser

Comment: On a SPA you only see the Index.html, so I think that is the expected behavior when using Create React App. If you want to serve any content for the public folder, you should do it through React and JavaScript.

Comment: MSW supports CRA, but note that CRA comes with _its own_ service worker, which is _disabled_ by default. One client (application) can have only 1 worker at a time. Since CRA calls "serviceWorker.unregister", it unregisters any other workers your app may establish (like the one from MSW). That's why you need to remove that line, as rightfully suggested.

Comment: The documentation won't mention any specific frameworks support because all frameworks are supported by default. Request interception happens on the network level with MSW, and request in any framework ends up in the network.

Comment: The difference in the worker scripts of MSW and CRA is substantial, as each aims to achieve its own goal (MSW—API mocking, CRA—assets caching). You can use `importScript` in a worker to combine both if that's truly your intent.